# JQuery UI Checkbox Values in Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to build a Preferences dialog using JQuery UI and its dialog. I have several checkboxes the user can set. When the dialog opens, I set these checkboxes based on an internal Preferences list.

This works fine the first time I display the dialog, but on subsequent opens the dialog retains its last settings, even when Preferences haven't changed. That is, the visual appearance is retained, while the Preferences values haven't been changed.

If I revert to using plain old HTML checkboxes, they work correctly. It's only the JQuery UI checkboxes that stubbornly hold onto their last state.

This seems to be a pernicious problem, but there aren't any clear answers or examples on how to fix it. One approach - manually destroying, then re-writing the entire dialog on every call - seems utterly frustrating, and I'm hoping there's some better way of handling this problem while still being able to use JQuery UI widgets.

Comment: How are you setting these checkboxes on the init?

Comment: I assume that you are not deleting the dialog from DOM but hiding and showing when you open it next time. 
make sure you delete everything when its closed.check http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/

Comment: When using modal dialogs I usually reset all my inputs just before the dialog opens using JQuery's `reset()` can you do that?

Comment: Scottie: I'm setting values with $("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true|false);

Comment: suish: not sure I'm following you. My form elements are defined in my HTML. If I remove the dialog from the DOM and all those elements, are you saying I have to dynamically recreated it on every open?

Comment: Edward - what reset() function are you referring to? I don't think JQuery has one. FWIW, this is a non-modal dialog, although I don't think that matters.

Comment: I was JUST doing to research on it, **reset is a JavaScript function, not JQuery; - my bad** but my point still stands, resetting the inputs just before the dialog loads would fix this.

Comment: @SixDegrees Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gc39k842/ does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by explicitly calling `button("refresh")` on every checkbox element when I detect an update or when reloading. This apparently is required to sync the JQUI appearance with the underlying form element's state.